Не можно найти модуль angular в проекте ASP.NET
Создаю проект ASP.NET + Angular. При этом получаю ошибки типа:
Cannot find module @angular/core or its corresponding type
declarations. Ну и другие angular-библиотеки тоже самое.
Переустанавливал локально npm командой npm install npm - не
помогло. Через терминал Visual Studio. Что не так может быть,
просьба помочь.
